# How to use MSSA(Microsoft Active Accessibility) with Delphi XE4?

Tags: delphi-xe4

I have the following code

```
uses
Windows,
{$ifndef COMPILER_10_UP}
MSAAIntf, // MSAA support for Delphi up to 2005
{$else}
oleacc, // MSAA support in Delphi 2006 or higher
{$endif COMPILER_10_UP}
```

But my compiler gives an Error saying Cannot Resolve unit name MSAAIntf

Comment: It seems which `COMPILER_10_UP`  is not defined, so the compiler try to use the `MSAAIntf` unit. Where  `COMPILER_10_UP` is defined?

Comment: It is defined in Compilers.inc file

Comment: Maybe the Compilers.inc file is not updated to check the Delphi-XE4 version, can you include the content of this file in the question?